# Display month and year specific datepicker in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

Is it possible to show a jquery inline datepicker by a specific month and year? Lets say I want to see the inline datepicker for Nov 2014. And it shows the complete month without selecting any date.

Comment: u don't want to show any dates..??

Comment: Am i get you correct that you want only specific dates it your data picker?

Comment: @Learner I want simple datepicker. The only thing that I want is just it goes to a specific month. Nothing else. I'll setDate later on using the method.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b0efyzcc/4/

Comment: @Learner Can you take a look over this fiddle? This is the only code we need to get it work. But unfortunately it isn't working.

http://jsfiddle.net/Superman/b0efyzcc/5/

Comment: @Superman acctually i customize jquery.ui.js file to get it work

Comment: @Learner It wasn't working at all. I was only able to select a date which then show as a month and year format in the input box. e.g December 2014. Please read my comments underneath the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only One. You can even create multiple instances of datepicker each of them will be of different month. [Look here](http://jsfiddle.net/LetMeCodeYou/yqkbo1v0/).

```
(function(){

    for( var i=0; i<5; i++ ){
    var dateObj = new Date();    
     dateObj.setMonth(i);
     dateObj.setYear(dateObj.getFullYear());
     var dp = $('<div id="calendar' + i + '" > </div>');
     $('#Calendar').append(dp);
        console.log("Month: "+dateObj.getMonth());
        dp.datepicker({defaultDate: dateObj});

    }

})();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [option-dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) like,

```
$(function() {
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'M yy'
     });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'M yy'
     });
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker"/>
```

If you want to showonly month and year drop down then try the below snippet

```js
$(function() {
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'M yy',
     });
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: Rohan The way first datepicker selects the date which is Only month and year. I want to specify it the same way before getting it instantiated or rendered on html page.

Comment: For example : dateFormat: 'Nov 2014'

Comment: When you select date then it will show the same format like 'Nov 2014'.

Comment: I have an array of months like this which contains [Jan 2014, Feb 2014, Mar 2014 ...] and before creating the datepicker. I want to provide this array to create an inline datepicker for each month.

Comment: In resultant I'll get 3 months calendar on the page, Jan 2014, Feb 2014 and Mar 2014.

Comment: Then you don't need the jquery ui datepicker, just make a plugin for it or you can code for it.

Comment: I'm coding for it and this is the issue where I stuck :)